# issues calling information from firebase to set button titles

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some information from firebase in order to set certain functions of a button. I am able to set the title and background color correctly. However, the button action is the same.

in my view, the user clicks a button that saves information to firebase, then the button title and background changes. when the user clicks the button the code that is initiated starts with handleConfirm. this code runs perfectly, saves all of the data to firebase, and what not.

```
    @objc func handleConfirm() {
           let workUser = self.workerUser
           let username = workUser?.name
           let post = notification?.poster
           let jobTitle = post?.category


           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ready? ",message:" Are you ready to complete the job \(jobTitle!) for \(username!) ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

           let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                  print("you pressed Yes, please button")
              })

           let continueButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Get to Work!", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            self.fetchJobProgress()
            self.updateNSaveJobProgress()
            let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
                  hud.textLabel.text = "Confirming!"
                    hud.show(in: self.view)


            hud.dismiss()
              })

           continueButton.setValue(GREEN_Theme, forKey: "titleTextColor")
           cancelButton.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
           alert.addAction(cancelButton)
           alert.addAction(continueButton)
           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func updateNSaveJobProgress() {
    let workUser = self.workerUser
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let workerId = workUser?.uid
    let address = workerUser?.address
     let createDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        let user = User(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])
        workUser?.uid = snapshot.key

        let docData: [String: Any] = ["workerId": uid!,
                                      "creationDate": createDate,
                                      "fromId" : workerId!,
                                      "location": address,
                                      "type": 2,
                                      "checked": 0,]

        self.postJobNotificationsIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: workerId!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
        self.updateUserDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
        JOB_POST_REF.child(uid!).child("progress?").setValue(2)

     }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

        print("Finished saving user info")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            print("Dismissal complete")
        })


    }

    private func updateUserDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
        hud.textLabel.text = "Saving"
        hud.show(in: view)

        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://oddjobs-b131f.firebaseio.com/")
                    let usersReference = ref.child("workInProgress").child(uid).childByAutoId()
                    usersReference.setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print("error saving data into firebase")
                        return
                    }

                    hud.dismiss()
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

    }

 private func postJobNotificationsIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://oddjobs-b131f.firebaseio.com/")
        let usersReference = ref.child("notifications").child(uid).childByAutoId()
        usersReference.setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print("error saving data into firebase")
            return
        }
    })
}
```

after this, we want to call fetchJobProgress() which sets up the views of the button if the user pressed the button once or twice. note, under

```
if type==userNotifications.NotificationType.inProgress.rawValue {
```

}

if I were to uncomment out isuserinteractionenabled = false, the user will not be able to interact with the button. Why?

```
func fetchJobProgress() {
        let workerId = workerUser?.uid
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("workInProgress").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId").queryEqual(toValue: workerId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        for (_, valueDic) in dictionary {
            guard let dic = valueDic as? [String: Any] else {
                continue
            }
            guard let type = dic["type"] as? Int else {
                continue
            }

            if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.inProgress.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.setTitle("In Progress...", for: .normal)
                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                //self.confirmButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleComplete), for: .touchUpInside)

            } else if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.accepted.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
                self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleConfirm), for: .touchUpInside)

            }  else if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.completed.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.setTitle("Completed!", for: .normal)
                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                self.confirmButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                           }

            break
        }





        }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

    }
```

Now this, perfectly sets the button color and title. however, the button's action is still handleConfirm instead of handle complete.

handle complete looks like

```
 @objc func handleComplete() {
           let workUser = self.workerUser
           let username = workUser?.name
           let post = notification?.poster
           let jobTitle = post?.category


           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Completed? ",message:" Did you complete the job \(jobTitle!) for \(username!) ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

           let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Not Yet!", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                  print("you pressed Yes, please button")
              })

           let continueButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Complete", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            self.fetchJobProgress()
            self.completeJobProgress()
            let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
                  hud.textLabel.text = "Confirming!"
                    hud.show(in: self.view)


            hud.dismiss()
              })

           continueButton.setValue(GREEN_Theme, forKey: "titleTextColor")
           cancelButton.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
           alert.addAction(cancelButton)
           alert.addAction(continueButton)
           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func completeJobProgress() {
    let workUser = self.workerUser
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let workerId = workUser?.uid
    let address = workerUser?.address
     let createDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        let user = User(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])
        workUser?.uid = snapshot.key

        let docData: [String: Any] = ["workerId": uid!,
                                      "creationDate": createDate,
                                      "fromId" : workerId!,
                                      "location": address!,
                                      "type": 3,
                                      "checked": 0,]

        self.setJobToCompletedInDatabase(uid: workerId!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
        self.updateUserDataIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid!, values: docData as [String : AnyObject])
        JOB_POST_REF.child(uid!).child("progress?").setValue(3)

     }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

        print("Finished saving user info")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            print("Dismissal complete")
        })


    }

    private func setJobToCompletedInDatabase(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)
        hud.textLabel.text = "Saving"
        hud.show(in: view)

        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://oddjobs-b131f.firebaseio.com/")
                    let usersReference = ref.child("completedJob").child(uid).childByAutoId()
                    usersReference.setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print("error saving data into firebase")
                        return
                    }

                    hud.dismiss()
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

    }
```

The code for both is very identical instead of a few minor changes but it is supposed to be saved in two different trees in firebase.

Since the background of the button color and title are successfully being changed, I don't get why the button's actions are not?

I can add pictures if this is too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the action first and then give new action to the button:

Follow the code:

```
self.confirmButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
```

Add this line whenever you set new action.

Updated method:

```
func fetchJobProgress() {
            let workerId = workerUser?.uid
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("workInProgress").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId").queryEqual(toValue: workerId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            for (_, valueDic) in dictionary {
                guard let dic = valueDic as? [String: Any] else {
                    continue
                }
                guard let type = dic["type"] as? Int else {
                    continue
                }

                if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.inProgress.rawValue {
                    self.confirmButton.setTitle("Pending...", for: .normal)
                    self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    self.confirmButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
                    self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleComplete), for: .touchUpInside)
                   // self.confirmButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                } else if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.completed.rawValue {
                    self.confirmButton.setTitle("completed", for: .normal)
                    self.confirmButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: [])
                    self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = .white
                    self.confirmButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                }
                else {
                    self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
                    self.confirmButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
                    self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleConfirm), for: .touchUpInside)

                }

                break
            }





            }, withCancel: { (err) in
            print("attempting to load information")
            })

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!!